# libcurl POST xml file to url

Tags: libcurl

I have been working on uploading a simple XML file to a specialized Web Server. This webserver only supports the use of POST or GET, so it eliminates the use of CURLOPT_UPLOAD which only provides for PUT.

I can use the command line to send the file using the following command line 
    curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' -H 'SOAP Action:' 
    -T igs_meters2.xml -X POST //url//

I tried to use CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_READDATA, but received a 413 Request Entity Too Large.

I know this cannot be this hard, but I am out in areas I have never work in. Thanks in advance for an idea.

SOLVED:
the tip about CUSTOMREQUEST was what I needed to find. That helped, and I also needed to add in an HTTPHEADER for CONTENT-TYPE and SOAPAction:

Comment: "This webserver only supports the use of POST or GET, so it eliminates the use of CURLOPT_UPLOAD which only provides for PUT" — no, you can still use CURLOPT_UPLOAD with POST: just change the HTTP method via CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST. This is a quirk in curl's design — the *treatment* of request and *HTTP method* are separate things. You select *treatment* via CURLOPT_UPLOAD/CURLOPT_POST and it decides the default HTTP method. But you can still override the method via CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.

Comment: Remember this trick: if you have a working command line just add `--libcurl example.c` to get a libcurl source code template doing the same thing your command line just did...

Comment: @user1643723 CUSTOMREQUEST was the tip I needed. Thank you